# Does the original HPCCG by Mantevo perform a preconditioned symmetric gauss Seidel smoother

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp, hpc

Does the original HPCCG by Mantevo perform a preconditioned symmetric gauss Seidel smoother because I can't seem to find this step in the code base. It only does a conjugate gradient in the HPCCG.cpp file.

https://github.com/Mantevo/HPCCG

Comment: opening a github issue on the project looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It does not have a preconditioned and it's not supposed to. I mixed it up with HPCG which does incorporate a precondtioner.